# Pseudo-answers are bad

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-question

Stack Exchange prides itself in having high quality content, therefore "making the Internet a better place." It's why I take issue with the answers to this question: [Comment perdre l'accent québécois?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1530/comment-perdre-laccent-quebecois)

Most of the answers are atrocious. A large number don't try to answer the question, at all, and are what we, on Skeptics, call pseudo-answers. Simply put, comments belong in the comment section. If the answer is, "How can I lose my regional accent?" then the answers should focus ways for one to lose his regional accent. An answer that doesn't do that is only seeming to answer the question, but doesn't answer it.

If you disagree with the premise of the question and want to share your disagreement with the rest of the world, do so in the comment section. The answer section is for actual answers.

Many of the question's answers should be either heavily downvoted or even deleted by moderators.

Comment: Related question complaining the opposite in the Japanese meta: https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/593/comments-are-not-for-answers/594#594

Comment: Borror0 is at best mistaken when saying "we ... call pseudo-answers". There's no "we" - only Borror0 himself does so: https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=pseudo-answers (This was posted previously, but was deleted by an admin)

Answer (score 5):

As I write, none of the answers has had a downvote, and none of the answers has been flagged.

Ok, reviewing the answers, three (the three that have one upvote) are poor answers but technically answers, while the other three (which have no upvote) are saying “don't do it”. Very well, now there are three answers.

Next time, please **flag for moderator attention** when you see something that you can't take care of by yourself. For example, if someone posts an answer that does not answer the question at all (“not even wrong”), click on “flag” and select “not an answer”. (If it's a wrong answer, downvote; moderators cannot do anything about wrong answers.)

---

À l'heure où j'écris, aucune des réponse n'a été moinsue, et aucune des réponses n'a été signalée.

En regardant les réponses de plus près, je vois que trois d'entre elles (les trois qui ont un vote pour) sont des réponses faibles, mais des réponses néanmoins. Les trois autres (celles qui n'ont aucun vote) ne répondent pas du tout à la question (elles disent juste de ne pas faire ça). Bon, maintenant il n'y a plus que trois réponses.

À l'avenir, merci de **signaler à l'attention des modérateurs** quand vous voyez quelque chose qui ne va pas sur le site et que vous ne pouvez pas y rémédier par vous-même. Par exemple, si vous voyez une réponse qui n'en est pas une (« même pas fausse »), cliquez sur « *flag* » et sélectionner « *not an answer* » (« pas une réponse »). (Si c'est une réponse fausse, moinssoyez ; les modérateurs ne peuvent rien faire avec une réponse fausse.)

Comment: Erm. Funny: while the post above (rightfully) points out that **Answers** are for topical answers to the question and that "don't do that" certainly shouldn't be an answer, your response as a moderator was to delete all the **comments** instead (which were of questionable interest, but that's what comments are for)... For the record (and as the author of one such comment), I think these comments were a gentle way of pointing out that this question might not be a very good one (at least not for FLU).

Comment: @Dave I deleted both the comments (which didn't seem to go anywhere) and the three answers that weren't answers. Comments are not meant for free-form discussions (there's chat for that). Apart from one comment (not yours) that essentially said “you can't”, none of the comments had any lasting value.

Comment: @Dave Answers have been deleted. Comments didn't bother me, but were not insightful enough to be mourned imho.

Comment: I thought of flagging those answers, but I wasn't sure if the reasoning was obvious enough, so I opted for a meta post instead. @Dave: I concur: the question wasn't very good and the premise was questionable, but that's no excuse. Broken windows are bad.

Comment: I don't care if my comments is being deleted, but at least send it back to me so that I can reuse the letters in other (equally stupid) comments.

Comment: @Joubarc Here you are, already sorted for easier recycling: `,,,.02Àaaaaaaaacccddddeeeeeeeeeeefhiiiiijllmnnnnnnnoooppprrrrrrrsssssssstttttuuuuvvvvyy`.

Comment: @Gilles: quelles sont les options pour signaler **à l'attention des modérateurs** ? Voir [cette question](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1635/regle-daccord-pour-les-aliments) et mon commentaire à M42. Je ne vois pas l'intérêt de la question telle qu'elle est posée mais je n'ai pas de raison de la flaguée. Encore moins de raison de gagner des points en transformant mon commentaire en réponse. Quelles autres options ai-je ?

Comment: @Laure Pour être sûr d'avoir l'attention des modérateurs, soulève un drapeau (*flag*). Si tu ne vois pas l'intérêt de la question, vote pour clore. Si tu veux en discuter avec la communauté plus généralemen, poste une question sur [meta](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/) ou discutes-en sur le [clavardage (chat)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1098/french-language-and-usage). En l'occurrence, je ne vois pas le problème, et « l'un ou l'autre se dit ou se disent » est une réponse valable.